# Android database framework for complex queries and comfortable engineering

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I've been using the native Android SQLite library in the last time, but I am not pleased with the re-usability and readability. There are some ORM database libraries I found for Android, but I wonder whether those are useful as I got a whole bunch of complex select and delete operations I have to be able to run.

Can you suggest me any appropriate library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried this once. Pretty good I must say.

http://ormlite.com/